# Leaflet Not Adding Tile Layer to Bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I am helping my students with a map of some data related to Hurricane Sandy. They have four tile layers (MapBox Street, MapBox Satellite, NOAA Satellite, and NOAA Inundation) and several vector layers.

When it first loads, the map shows the MapBox Streets tiles with some vector data on top, with the ability to switch to the MapBox Satellite layer as the base map. Users can then add the inundation layer on top of the base map (the inundation layer is complex enough that it needs tiles instead of rendered polygons).

The problem occurs when you switch base map layers after the inundation layer has been added to the map. My students use the [L.map.addLayer(*data*, *insertAtTheBottom*)](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-addlayer) function to add the new base map layer to the bottom (after removing the old one), but for some reason the layer is only added below the vector layers and not below the inundation tile layer. When the base layers are switching out you can clearly see that the inundation tile layer is still there, it just won't go on top of the new base layer.

Does anyone know why this is the case? The documentation states that this parameter ensures that the new layer will be added below *all* other layers.

Live example of the page: http://personal.psu.edu/rsm5068/src/map.html

Relevant code segment

```
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="controls">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggleSatellite" /><label for="toggleSatellite">Toggle Satellite</label>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var map = null,
        layerStreets,
        layerSatelliteNow,
        layerSatelliteThen,
        layer1MSurge,
        layer3MSurge,
        lgrpBase,
        lgrpSurge;

    map = L.map("map", {
      'center' : L.latLng(40.7127, -74.0059),
      'zoom' : 10,
      'minZoom' : 9,
      'maxZoom' : 16
    })

    // ---- Tile Layers ----

    layerStreets = L.mapbox.tileLayer("user.id");
    layerSatelliteNow = L.mapbox.tileLayer("user.id");
    layer1MSurge = L.mapbox.tileLayer("user.id");
    layer3MSurge = L.mapbox.tileLayer("user.id");

    lgrpSurge = L.layerGroup();
    lgrpSurge
      .addLayer(layer3MSurge)
      .addLayer(layer1MSurge);

    // ---- Adding Data to Map ----

    map
      .setMaxBounds(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(40.4600,-74.33),L.latLng(40.9400,-73.667)))
      .addLayer(layerStreets)
      .addLayer(lgrpSurge)
      .addLayer(fgrpEvacCenters);

    // ---- Interactivity ----

    $("#toggleSatellite").change(function () {
      if ($("input[id='toggleSatellite']:checked").length > 0) {
        map
          .removeLayer(layerStreets)
          .addLayer(layerSatelliteNow, true);
      } else {
        map
          .removeLayer(layerSatelliteNow)
          .addLayer(layerStreets, true);
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Inundation layer should be added to the map as an `overlay` and not as a `basemap` (tiled layers can be overlays as well as basemaps).

First you'll want to distinguish between your basemap layers and your overlays.

Your basemap layers (streets, satellite, etc) are those layers that are mutually exclusive and should always be on the bottom.

Your overlay layers are not mutually exclusive and will always sit on top of the basemap layers.

The following example is from the [Leaflet LayersControl docs page](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html)

```
var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/API-key/{styleId}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    cloudmadeAttribution = 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2011 CloudMade';

var minimal   = L.tileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {styleId: 22677, attribution: cloudmadeAttribution}),
    midnight  = L.tileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {styleId: 999,   attribution: cloudmadeAttribution}),
    motorways = L.tileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {styleId: 46561, attribution: cloudmadeAttribution});

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: new L.LatLng(39.73, -104.99),
    zoom: 10,
    layers: [minimal, motorways, cities]
});

var baseMaps = {
    "Minimal": minimal,
    "Night View": midnight
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "Motorways": motorways,
    "Cities": cities
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

At this point, the basemaps (Minimal and Night View) will always be underneath the overlays (Motorways and Cities).

Make sure your Inundation layer is added to the map as an `overlay` and not a `basemap`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I still think this behavior is quite odd, given the documentation for map.addLayer() explicitly says "the layer is inserted under _all_ others" (emphasis mine). If this is a special case it needs to be outlined in some way, or made not so special.

Comment: Happy to help.  I agree the docs are a bit misleading. Saw some discussion of those docs [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/ipkoggIctLc).  Alternatively, you might also try bringToBack().

Answer (score 1):

This I think is a bug. I have tried it too but it is not working correctly. Please use  bringToBack() (or bringToFront() if you want it in front) to force layer to correct position:
So:
map.addLayer(layerSatelliteNow);
layerSatelliteNow.bringToBack();

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this solution and it works pretty well. I found the best result was to call bringToBack() on the variable I store each layer into inside a 'load' event handler. Sorry I can't select 2 answers as the correct answer.